# Show Action Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm trying to display a single scraped statement on a single show page but it's not working.

This is the error I get: (screenshot)

[image]

Here's the controller with the show action in it:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController

        def index 
            @links = Link.all 
        end

        def show
            @link = Link.find(params[:id])
        end 

    def craigslist_scrape
        require 'open-uri'

        url = "https://losangeles.craigslist.org/search/web"

        page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

        @craigslist_info = page.css("ul.rows")

                @link_info = page.css("li.result-row p.result-info a.result-title.hdrlnk")
                @date = page.css("li.result-row p.result-info time.result-date")

            @link_info.each_with_index do |link, index|
            Link.new(:link_info => link.text, :date => @date[index].text).save
            end
    end



   private
    def set_link
      @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    end

    def link_params
      params.require(:link).permit(:link_info, :date)
    end
```

Link Model:

```
class Link < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'links#craigslist_scrape'

    resources :links
end
```

craigslist.html.erb, where I put the show link as well:

```
<% @link_info.each_with_index do |link, index| %>
  <h2><%= "Title of the job: #{link.text}" %></h2>
  <p><%= "Date: #{@date[index].text}" %></p>
  <h6><%= link_to 'Show', link_path(link) %></h6>
<% end %>
```

show.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <strong>Link:</strong>
  <%= @link.link_info %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Date:</strong>
  <%= @link.date %>
</p>
```

---

Attaching the screenshot of `craigslist_scrape.html.erb` ...

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me what is the value in `link` variable in loop?

Comment: @ashvin, not sure if I understood your question correctly .. let me know if my answer doesn't answer it ... it's a craigslist link ... let me attach a screenshot of `craigslist.html.erb` ... the `show` action in there goes to the screenshot posted in the question above ...

Comment: @if you're asking what I see when I hover the show action in the second screenshot ... it starts with `http://localhost:3000/links/ etc ...` ... does that help?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, along with "[mcve]". Please do NOT use images to provide errors or source that is essential to the question. Links rot and break, causing the question to lose important information, and images can't be searched by the search engines making your question much harder for others to find. Instead copy and paste the pertinent information into your question, formatting it appropriately.

Comment: Also, please do not use "edit" or "update" type tags in the text. Instead, incorporate the changes into the text as if that new information had been there all along. We can see what changed and when it changed if we need to know.

Comment: @theTinMan, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your `craigslist` action you create `Link` by

```
 ...
 ...
 Link.new(:link_info => link.text, :date => @date[index].text).save
 ...
 ...
```

So in your `show` action you can find by `link_info` and in your show action should be:

```
def show
  @link = Link.find_by(link_info: params[:id])
end
```

and you need to update code in your `craigslist.html.erb`

```
<h6><%= link_to 'Show', link_path(link.text) %></h6>
```

Comment: I get a strange error. Have enclosed a screenshot underneath `2nd EDIT` ...

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 You need to create `show.html.erb` under `links` folder in view.

Comment: Error is for missing template.

Comment: @ashvin ... I know that's why I'm so puzzled about it ... there is a `show.html.erb` underneath `links` folder in view

Comment: @ashvin, have included a screenshot of the directory in `3rd EDIT`

Comment: it seems the problem is not missing file `show.html.erb`, but  how you call `show` action(navigate to show action).

Comment: @sreangrathanak, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

From your scrrenshot, I understand that in `link_path(link)` at `craigslist.html.erb` Line no: 3 you are passing url.

You should pass `Id` of `Link`, and if you want to get link from `URL` then you can do like

```
Link.find_by_text(params[:id])
```

If text is column in table.

---

```
Link.find_by_link_info(params[:id])
```

Comment: `text` is not a column in Link table ... it's `link_info` and `date`

Comment: Can you pass `id` of link in `link_path` if you have ?

Comment: @not sure what you mean, but when I hovered the show link as seen in second screenshot, it shows `localhost:3000/links/THEN-THE-NAME-OF-THE-LINK ... and I noticed something in the url ... including it in `4th EDIT` screenshot

Comment: the screenshot in the `4th EDIT` shows the text of `link_info` ... not the `id`